# Install4j running Executable not using environment variables

Tags: batch-file, groovy, environment-variables, install4j

I am trying to run a groovy script using Install4j. I have laid down the files for groovy and added to an environment variable "Groovy_Home". Then I added that to the Path Environment Variable. When I open the command window I am able to run "Groovy buildenv.groovy". It works! Almost magically! However when I use Install4j to create the .bat file that has a working dir of the .groovy file and runs this script:

```
@echo on

groovy buildenv.groovy > buildenv.output.log
```

It doesn't seem to work! it complains that it has no idea where the groovy is at. I have added the "Specific environment variables" to "PATH=${PATH}". But that doesn't seem to work either... Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the "Include parent environment variables" property of the "Run executable or batch file" action is selected.

If yes, select the "Show console window" property and its "Keep console window" child property and add

SET

to your batch file so you can check the environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to use *Specific environment variables* as you told, but not setting `PATH=${PATH}` (what it does if path is already set?).

Instead in the installer process I add a step of *Directory selection* type to let user choose the directory where groovy is installed, and use the user entry to set a installer variable. Then I use this variable in the *Specific environment variables* property of the *Run executable or batch file* action to set something like `PATH=${installer:userGroovyHome}`, where `userGroovyHome` is the *Variable name for selection* property of *Directory selection*